# how to save related data from file in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a file with lines of two integer separated by ','. I just want to store this integers from each line related together.
example :
file:

```
12,23
45,6545
12,89
```

I want to save 12 and 23 or 45 and 6545 both related together which I could call em 'both' or 'one by one' later .

### Thank you

update, Dear @MaxU
I have a file named 'A'

```
A:
36,89
65,84
52,999
1,7
```

each two numbers in one line are a pair and I want to use them together or separately in calculations ... .

Comment: it's not clear what you are going to achieve and what do you expect as a result... could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
nums = []
with open("yourfile.txt","r") as f:
     for line in f:
         nums.append(line)
```

Now, each line is stored together in an index of the array.  If you want to access the values one by one, you can just iterate and split:

```
for i in nums:
    print(i.split(",")[0] + " " + i.split(",")[1])
```

To access them together, just go through the indexed of the array.

Comment: Thank you, but in running I got this error: NameError: name 'mums' is not defined